# Dropdowns Django with dynamic list

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to give a drop-down menu from Django, from a dynamic list. For example, every time I run the model it should take columns names of a dataset and these names shall appear on the drop-down menu.

Previously, I have used a text box from Django which looks something like this:

> Forms.py

```
    from django import forms

    class LinearForm(forms.Form):

        Column_name1 = forms.CharField()
```

I have seen `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField()` and `forms.ChoiceField()` which takes choices as a list of values, since I need to generate a dynamic list from my `Views.py`. How do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can override form `__init__` method to do this

```
class LeniarForm(forms.Form):

    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('choices', [])
        super(LeniarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice_field'].choices = choices
```

> views.py

```
from .forms import LeniarForm

def my_view(request):
    # ....
    dynamic_choices = (('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'))
    f = LeniarForm(choices=dynamic_choices)
    # ....
```

Comment: that was amazing, I still need to look what *args and **kwargs. But as of now, I how to like to know one thing I hope I will be able to retrieve the value from f.cleaned_data['choice_field'] ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer:) but unfortunately, I am unable to upvote it due to reputation. Although I am not able to retrieve the data from f.cleaned_data['choice_field'] .

Comment: @PradeepKumar you need to call `f.is_valid()` before you access `f.cleaned_data['choice_field']`.

Comment: My bad, it was a silly mistake, I wasn't taking request.POST to f. Thanks for the support @Anjaneyulu Batta

Comment: can you explain what exactly __init__ is doing?  Can you explain what exactly __init__ is doing?

Comment: taking choices as input and assigning it to form field